# Why a 2D array is used for stack? Why cant a 1D array be used for a stack?

Tags: c, stack

Here, `s[20][20]` is declared in function `pre_post`. But the `push` operation involves pushing a string into stack s. How is that done? Why cant we execute the program with a 1D array for s like `s[20]` for stack??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void push(char item[],int *top,char s[][20])    //Pushes the symbol item onto stack s
{
  *top=*top+1;                                  //Top is incremented
  strcpy(s[*top],item);                         //Item is actually written onto stack
}

char *pop(int *top,char s[][20])                //Pops out the topmost element of stack s
{
  char *item;
  item=s[*top];
  *top=*top-1;
  return item;
}

void pre_post(char prefix[],char postfix[])     //Function to convert prefix to postfix
{
  char s[20][20];
  int top,i;
  char symbol,ch[2];
  char *op1,*op2;

  top=-1;
  for(i=strlen(prefix)-1;i>=0;i--)              //Scans the expression in   reverse manner
  {
    symbol=prefix[i];                           //The last symbol is scanned first
    ch[0]=symbol;
    ch[1]='\0';
    switch (symbol)                             //Checks whether the symbol is one among fiveoperators given.(next line)
                                                //If yes then execute the corresponding statements
    {
      case '+':
      case '-':
      case '*':
      case '/':
      case '^':
        op1=pop(&top,s);                        //The topmost operand of stack s is popped and stored as op1
        op2=pop(&top,s);                        //The next operand of stack s is popped and stored as op2

        strcpy(postfix,op1);                    //Copies the op1 into postfix
        strcat(postfix,op2);                    //Concatenates the op2 with postfix
        strcat(postfix,ch);                     //Concatenates the ch with postfix
        push(postfix,&top,s);                   //Pushes the postfix onto stack s
        break;
      default:
        if(isalnum(symbol))                     //It means that switch case is not satisfied i.e. symbol is a operand
          push(ch,&top,s);                      //Pushes the operand onto the stack s 
    }
  }

}

int main()
{
  char prefix[20];
  char postfix[20];
  printf("\n\n Enter the prefix expression \n\n");
  gets(prefix);
  pre_post(prefix,postfix);
  printf("\n\n The postfix expression is %s \n\n",postfix);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your stack is an array of *strings*, each of which is stored as an array of `char`, hence the need for a 2-d array.

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Does this code work properly ?

Comment: Yes. It works properly

Comment: Here that stack content is string so used 2d array of char. Here instead of 2 d array can use 1d array of char pointer but then need to handle memory allocation for strings

Comment: What are the advantages of Postfix expressions over prefix expressions?

Answer (score 2):

You need a 1-d array of characters to represent a string.

```
char str[20]; // An array of characters that can hold a string
              // of up to 19 characters.
```

Then, you need a 2-d array of characters to represent an array of strings.

```
char str[100][20]; // An array 100 strings. Each element of the array
                   // can hold a string of up to 19 characters.
```

Comment: How will the concatenation of string work in the given code? Can you please explain. I want to know whether a concatenated string (like AB+)is present in a single array element or would it be there in consecutive three array elements?

Comment: I don't see any code to concatenate strings. I only see a line that copies a string. `strcpy(s[*top],item);`

Comment: strcpy(postfix,op1);                   
        strcat(postfix,op2);                    
        strcat(postfix,ch);

Comment: @SameerKatti, I see it now. The concatenated string is stored only in `postfix`. It does not change the contents of the 2-d array. It only changes `postfix`, which is a separate string, independent of the array of strings.

Comment: These statements. I want to know if they are done as op1 is copied into postfix and then op2 is concatenated and finally ch is concatenated. Whether in the concatenated string, they are present in a single place (like in postfix[i]) or consecutive three places(like postfix[0], postfix[1], postfix[2]...

Comment: Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat. Hopefully that will answer some of your questions.

Comment: @R Sahu Thank you sir. Got it.